# how to outside files from c# and wait till the process complete

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio-2012

I am using visual studio 2012 and windows 8.1 64-bit
I like to execute python file from the visual studio using c# I have tried this code below

```
Process api = new Process();
api.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\Python34\python.exe";
api.StartInfo.Arguments = "c:\Python34\search_test.py";
api.Start();
```

I am getting error of Unrecognised escape sequence but, when I run below code it is running perfectly fine

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\python34\api.bat");
```

inside the bat file I am executing this

```
c:\Python34\python.exe c:\Python34\search_test.py
```

But i would like to wait till the process complete and execute the next line after the above program is closed

please Suggest me how to do that TIA

Comment: Though it only says it supports C and C++ (not sure what it does with C#), Cython (http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html) allows Python to call C functions and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Process api = new Process();
api.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
api.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C c:\Python34\python.exe c:\Python34\search_test.py";
api.Start();
```